# How to print return value of method in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, return, ipython

```
class Queue():
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def Enqueue(self,item):
        return self.items.insert(0, item)

    def Size(self):
        return len(self.items)

    def Dequeue(self):
        return self.items.pop()

Q = Queue()    
def Hotpot(namelist,num):

    for name in namelist:
        Q.Enqueue(name)

    while Q.Size() > 1:
        for i in range(num):
           Q.Enqueue(Q.Dequeue())
        Q.Dequeue()
    return Q.Dequeue() # I would like to print and see what is getting removed, I tried with x = Q.Dequeue(), print x and print Q.Dequeue() but im getting "None"



print Hotpot(['A','B','C','D','E','F'],7)
```

Hi Team,
I am trying above code for checking Queue, here I would like to print which value is removing each cycle. While printing I am getting none oly, please help me what changes I have to do for my expectation.

Comment: why don't you use `collections.deque`?

Comment: this code works for me. No `None`.

Comment: Hint: What do the loop above your return statement do?

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for your reply, yes this code works for me as well it ll return C at last but I would like to print every item of removal one by one, print Q.Dequeue, when put this in program iam getting C and None

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know what's goingto be returned, you need to save it locally, print what you saved, then return what you saved.  Something like:

```
    x = Q.Dequeue()
    print(x)
    return x
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code works for me, when you change `Q.Dequeue()` by `print Q.Dequeue()`.
Better python would be:

```
from collections import deque

def hotspot(names, num):
    queue = deque(reversed(names))
    while len(queue)>1:
        queue.rotate(num)
        print queue.pop()
    return queue.pop()

print hotspot(['A','B','C','D','E','F'], 7)
```